# Django Haystack and Elasticsearch Error Using rebuild_index

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I want to use elasticsearch engine for django-haystack. I was able to install every modules and packages successfully.

I run this command

> sudo service elasticsearch start

, below is the result.

```
* Starting ElasticSearch Server                                         [ OK ]
```

After that, I run

> python manage.py rebuild_index

It bring out this error

```
WARNING: This will irreparably remove EVERYTHING from your search index in connection 'default'.
Your choices after this are to restore from backups or rebuild via the `rebuild_index` command.
Are you sure you wish to continue? [y/N] yes

Removing all documents from your index because you said so.
Failed to clear Elasticsearch index: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=9200): Max retries exceeded with url: /haystack (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
All documents removed.
Indexing 457 finhalls
ERROR:root:Error updating nateapp using default

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=9200): Max retries exceeded with url: /_bulk (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

Elasticsearchlog file:

```
   [2013-12-31 17:17:40,635][INFO ][node                     ] [Garrison Kane] version[0.90.9], pid[17314], build[a968646/2013-12-23T10:35:28Z]
[2013-12-31 17:17:40,635][INFO ][node                     ] [Garrison Kane] initializing ...
[2013-12-31 17:17:40,645][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Garrison Kane] loaded [], sites []
[2013-12-31 17:17:44,058][INFO ][node                     ] [Garrison Kane] initialized
[2013-12-31 17:17:44,059][INFO ][node                     ] [Garrison Kane] starting ...
[2013-12-31 17:17:44,195][INFO ][transport                ] [Garrison Kane] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/192.241.129.232:9300]}
[2013-12-31 17:17:47,255][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Garrison Kane] new_master [Garrison Kane][467vjQt7RTyOg8IEHSMKBg][inet[/192.241.129.232:9300]], reason: ze$
[2013-12-31 17:17:47,303][INFO ][discovery                ] [Garrison Kane] elasticsearch/467vjQt7RTyOg8IEHSMKBg
[2013-12-31 17:17:47,342][INFO ][http                     ] [Garrison Kane] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/192.241.129.232:9200]}
[2013-12-31 17:17:47,343][INFO ][node                     ] [Garrison Kane] started
[2013-12-31 17:17:47,372][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Garrison Kane] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
[2013-12-31 17:17:59,480][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Garrison Kane] [haystack] creating index, cause [api], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2013-12-31 17:18:00,194][DEBUG][action.admin.indices.mapping.put] [Garrison Kane] failed to put mappings on indices [[haystack]], type [modelresult]
org.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException: bool field can't be tokenized
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.BooleanFieldMapper$Builder.tokenized(BooleanFieldMapper.java:93)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.BooleanFieldMapper$Builder.tokenized(BooleanFieldMapper.java:76)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.TypeParsers.parseIndex(TypeParsers.java:185)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.TypeParsers.parseField(TypeParsers.java:75)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.BooleanFieldMapper$TypeParser.parse(BooleanFieldMapper.java:108)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parseProperties(ObjectMapper.java:262)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parse(ObjectMapper.java:218)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parse(DocumentMapperParser.java:201)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parseCompressed(DocumentMapperParser.java:183)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.parse(MapperService.java:322)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.parse(MapperService.java:318)
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataMappingService$5.execute(MetaDataMappingService.java:533)
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask.run(InternalClusterService.java:300)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:135)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
[2013-12-31 17:23:36,774][INFO ][node                     ] [Rock Python] version[0.90.9], pid[17565], build[a968646/2013-12-23T10:35:28Z]
[2013-12-31 17:23:36,775][INFO ][node                     ] [Rock Python] initializing ...
[2013-12-31 17:23:36,783][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Rock Python] loaded [], sites []
[2013-12-31 17:23:40,156][INFO ][node                     ] [Rock Python] initialized
[2013-12-31 17:23:40,156][INFO ][node                     ] [Rock Python] starting ...
[2013-12-31 17:23:40,310][INFO ][transport                ] [Rock Python] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/192.241.129.232:9300]}
[2013-12-31 17:23:43,390][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Rock Python] new_master [Rock Python][mWPUd96mQyqnlBriAgy-9Q][inet[/192.241.129.232:9300]], reason: zen-di$
[2013-12-31 17:23:43,430][INFO ][discovery                ] [Rock Python] elasticsearch/mWPUd96mQyqnlBriAgy-9Q
[2013-12-31 17:23:43,457][INFO ][http                     ] [Rock Python] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/192.241.129.232:9200]}
[2013-12-31 17:23:43,458][INFO ][node                     ] [Rock Python] started
[2013-12-31 17:23:44,424][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Rock Python] recovered [1] indices into cluster_state
[2013-12-31 17:35:55,614][INFO ][node                     ] [Wraith] version[0.90.9], pid[755], build[a968646/2013-12-23T10:35:28Z]
[2013-12-31 17:35:55,618][INFO ][node                     ] [Wraith] initializing ...
[2013-12-31 17:35:55,638][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Wraith] loaded [], sites []
[2013-12-31 17:35:59,536][INFO ][node                     ] [Wraith] initialized
[2013-12-31 17:35:59,537][INFO ][node                     ] [Wraith] starting ...
[2013-12-31 17:35:59,708][INFO ][transport                ] [Wraith] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/192.241.129.232:9300]}
[2013-12-31 17:36:02,785][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Wraith] new_master [Wraith][5Jgys5vjRcah6LIbcPPecQ][inet[/192.241.129.232:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join ($
[2013-12-31 17:36:02,829][INFO ][discovery                ] [Wraith] elasticsearch/5Jgys5vjRcah6LIbcPPecQ
[2013-12-31 17:36:02,861][INFO ][http                     ] [Wraith] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/192.241.129.232:9200]}
[2013-12-31 17:36:02,862][INFO ][node                     ] [Wraith] started
[2013-12-31 17:36:04,072][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Wraith] recovered [1] indices into cluster_state
[2013-12-31 17:37:23,469][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Wraith] [haystack] deleting index
[2013-12-31 17:37:23,726][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Wraith] [haystack] creating index, cause [api], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2013-12-31 17:37:24,200][DEBUG][action.admin.indices.mapping.put] [Wraith] failed to put mappings on indices [[haystack]], type [modelresult]
org.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException: bool field can't be tokenized
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.BooleanFieldMapper$Builder.tokenized(BooleanFieldMapper.java:93)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.BooleanFieldMapper$Builder.tokenized(BooleanFieldMapper.java:76)
         at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.TypeParsers.parseIndex(TypeParsers.java:185)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.TypeParsers.parseField(TypeParsers.java:75)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.BooleanFieldMapper$TypeParser.parse(BooleanFieldMapper.java:108)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parseProperties(ObjectMapper.java:262)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parse(ObjectMapper.java:218)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parse(DocumentMapperParser.java:201)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parseCompressed(DocumentMapperParser.java:183)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.parse(MapperService.java:322)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.parse(MapperService.java:318)
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataMappingService$5.execute(MetaDataMappingService.java:533)
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask.run(InternalClusterService.java:300)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:135)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
[2013-12-31 17:37:26,856][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Wraith] [haystack] update_mapping [modelresult] (dynamic)
[2013-12-31 17:50:56,446][INFO ][node                     ] [Nikki] version[0.90.9], pid[754], build[a968646/2013-12-23T10:35:28Z]
[2013-12-31 17:50:56,446][INFO ][node                     ] [Nikki] initializing ...
[2013-12-31 17:50:56,462][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Nikki] loaded [], sites []
[2013-12-31 17:50:59,849][INFO ][node                     ] [Nikki] initialized
[2013-12-31 17:50:59,850][INFO ][node                     ] [Nikki] starting ...
[2013-12-31 17:50:59,977][INFO ][transport                ] [Nikki] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/192.241.129.232:9300]}
[2013-12-31 17:51:03,174][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Nikki] new_master [Nikki][e-voUaukTnKHaj50uQDsrA][inet[/192.241.129.232:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join (el$
[2013-12-31 17:51:03,227][INFO ][discovery                ] [Nikki] elasticsearch/e-voUaukTnKHaj50uQDsrA
[2013-12-31 17:51:03,264][INFO ][http                     ] [Nikki] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/192.241.129.232:9200]}
[2013-12-31 17:51:03,265][INFO ][node                     ] [Nikki] started
[2013-12-31 17:51:04,622][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Nikki] recovered [1] indices into cluster_state
[2013-12-31 17:52:20,253][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Nikki] [haystack] deleting index
[2013-12-31 17:52:20,496][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Nikki] [haystack] creating index, cause [api], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2013-12-31 17:52:20,973][DEBUG][action.admin.indices.mapping.put] [Nikki] failed to put mappings on indices [[haystack]], type [modelresult]
org.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException: bool field can't be tokenized
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.BooleanFieldMapper$Builder.tokenized(BooleanFieldMapper.java:93)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.BooleanFieldMapper$Builder.tokenized(BooleanFieldMapper.java:76)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.TypeParsers.parseIndex(TypeParsers.java:185)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.TypeParsers.parseField(TypeParsers.java:75)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.BooleanFieldMapper$TypeParser.parse(BooleanFieldMapper.java:108)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parseProperties(ObjectMapper.java:262)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parse(ObjectMapper.java:218)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parse(DocumentMapperParser.java:201)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parseCompressed(DocumentMapperParser.java:183)
         at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.parse(MapperService.java:322)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.parse(MapperService.java:318)
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataMappingService$5.execute(MetaDataMappingService.java:533)
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask.run(InternalClusterService.java:300)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:135)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
[2013-12-31 17:52:23,817][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Nikki] [haystack] update_mapping [modelresult] (dynamic)
[2013-12-31 21:14:55,585][INFO ][node                     ] [Wingfoot, Wyatt] version[0.90.9], pid[753], build[a968646/2013-12-23T10:35:28Z]
[2013-12-31 21:14:55,588][INFO ][node                     ] [Wingfoot, Wyatt] initializing ...
[2013-12-31 21:14:55,604][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Wingfoot, Wyatt] loaded [], sites []
[2013-12-31 21:14:59,147][INFO ][node                     ] [Wingfoot, Wyatt] initialized
[2013-12-31 21:14:59,148][INFO ][node                     ] [Wingfoot, Wyatt] starting ...
[2013-12-31 21:14:59,275][INFO ][transport                ] [Wingfoot, Wyatt] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/192.241.129.232:9300]}
[2013-12-31 21:15:02,599][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Wingfoot, Wyatt] new_master [Wingfoot, Wyatt][lRhJ4RD0Q9uLoHbaYCPFzA][inet[/192.241.129.232:9300]], reason$
[2013-12-31 21:15:02,648][INFO ][discovery                ] [Wingfoot, Wyatt] elasticsearch/lRhJ4RD0Q9uLoHbaYCPFzA
[2013-12-31 21:15:02,682][INFO ][http                     ] [Wingfoot, Wyatt] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/192.241.129.232:9200]}
[2013-12-31 21:15:02,683][INFO ][node                     ] [Wingfoot, Wyatt] started
[2013-12-31 21:15:04,150][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Wingfoot, Wyatt] recovered [1] indices into cluster_state
```

Search_index.py

```
class FinhallIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text=indexes.CharField(document=True,use_template=True)
    name=indexes.CharField(model_attr='name')
    address=indexes.CharField(model_attr='address')

    def get_model(self):
        return Finhall

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(pub_date__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
```

I installed elasticsearch through .deb

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you verified that elasticsearch is running? Are there any errors in /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log?

Comment: Here's what is in my log file /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log
 at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.parse(MapperService.jav$
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataMappingService$5.execute($
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask.$
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecuto$
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
[2013-12-31 17:52:23,817][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Nikki] [haystack] $

Comment: I'll need more of the log, the error itself is not in that snippet. Please edit your question with the full error

Comment: kindly check the question

Comment: Sorry, but the log is still cut off at the right side...

Comment: kindly check it out. it has been fixed properly.

Comment: Can you share your related models and search_index.py file?

Comment: I've added my search_index.py file to the question.

Comment: can you try my answer and see if I am correct?

Answer (score 2):

It's a haystack issue https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/issues/866

Set indexed=False on your BooleanFields

Comment: not using elasticsearch for now. will check it out later. :)